# How can switch branch after I do 'repo init'

Tags: git, repository

I have created my repository like this:

```
 repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.0.1_r1
```

But how can I

- find out what other branches are there for my repo
- switch to another branch for my repo

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```sh
# find out what other branches are there for my repo
git branch -a

# switch to another branch for my repo    
git checkout foo
```

PS stop using repo and just use git.